# String replaceAll GWT and OBF compilation mode

Tags: java, regex, gwt

When I run code bellow I'm getting error: "(TyperError) f is undefined"
I'm getting this error when I complie in OFB style.
When I use PRETTY style it is working correcly.

GWT version: 2.4

```
public static String replaceCommaWithDotInFloat(String text) {
    String result = replaceCommaWithDot(DATA_DELIMITER, text, DATA_DELIMITER);
    result = replaceCommaWithDot(LINE_DELIMITER, result, LINE_DELIMITER);
    result = replaceCommaWithDot(LINE_DELIMITER, result, DATA_DELIMITER);
    result = replaceCommaWithDot(DATA_DELIMITER, result, LINE_DELIMITER);
    return result;
}

private static String replaceCommaWithDot(String startsWith, String text, String endsWith) {
    return text.replaceAll(startsWith + "([+-]?\\d+),(\\d+)" + endsWith, startsWith + "$1.$2" + endsWith);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are getting that error, but inserting the string directly into the regex is bad news. Try escaping startsWith and endsWith in the regex param with Pattern.quote, and escape them in the replacement string with Matcher.quoteReplacement.

Answer (score 0):

Update to GWT 2.5.1 helped. Looks like a bug in GWT 2.4 complier.

Answer (score 0):

GWT 2.8 does not have the issue, either. However, your code is still not safe (see nhahtdh's remark).

You are passing literal texts as `startsWith` and `endsWith`, thus you need to *quote* these values when building a dynamic regex pattern with [`RegExp#quote(java.lang.String input)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html#quote-java.lang.String-). When you replace with those values, make sure you escape the `$` char (if followed with a digit, it will form a backreference and that might lead to an exception, e.g. `String endsWith = "\\$1"`). Better: just capture these delimiters, and use backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Use

```
private static String replaceCommaWithDot(String startsWith, String text, String endsWith) {
    return text.replaceAll("(" + RegExp.quote(startsWith) + ")([+-]?\\d+),(\\d+)(" + RegExp.quote(endsWith) + ")", "$1$2.$3$4");
}
```